# How do I display a single new word of a paragraph at a time, moving by keypress or mouseclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have something like this:

```
<p>Here are several words in a sentence.</p>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to display each word, one by one, via keypress or mouseclick, till it reaches the end.

So for example:

Here (click)
Here are (click)
Here are several , etc.

This may be basic, but I'm not very good and I'd love some help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This has been turned into a jQuery Plugin: [word-reveal](https://github.com/mathieujonson/word-reveal/).

While the other two answers will work ([sort of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23765469/how-do-i-display-a-single-new-word-of-a-paragraph-at-a-time-moving-by-keypress#comment-36558364)), they aren't very reusable.  What happens when you have more than one container you'd like to reveal with more than one sentence?  I created a [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/mathieujonson/word-reveal/) that can easily be reused throughout the page.

**The Setup**

- Include [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the page
- Download the plugin from [GitHub](https://github.com/mathieujonson/word-reveal/), and include it on the page
- You're set and ready to go!

**The HTML**

Set an `id` for each `div` or `p` tag.  An example of multiple uses:

```
<p id="firstRevealer"></p>
<p id="secondRevealer"></p>
<p id="thirdRevealer"></p>
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#firstRevealer").wordReveal({text:"This reveals one word at a time."});
    $("#secondRevealer").wordReveal({text:"Adding more text is easy!"});
    $("#thirdRevealer").wordReveal({text:"It <b>also</b> works on <em>some</em> tags, since it splits on <b>spaces</b>!"});
});
```

**The CSS**

I added CSS on the example, to make clear where you're clicking to reveal the next word.  A different answer registered clicks on the `document`, but *any* clicks (for a expandable menu, for example) would add a word.

```
p { 
    padding: 10px; 
    margin:10px; 
    min-height:25px; 
    background-color:#BADA55 
}
```

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mathieujonson/SdW3H/).

**Note**

This can easily be extended to act on other events (keypress).

Answer (score 1):

I just want to make some interventions on @Dean.DePue answer and make the code so you paste it in your project and does the trick:

Your html should look like this:

```
<div id="adiv"></div>
```

And you should add this javascript code too:

```
var index, newsentence, sentence, words;
sentence = "Here are several words in a sentence";
words = sentence.split(" ");
index = 0;
newsentence = "";

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (e.button === 0 && index < words.length) {
    newsentence += words[index];
    newsentence += " ";
    $("#adiv").html(newsentence);
    index = index + 1;
  }
});
```

If you've got any doubt of the code just ask!

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sentence = "Here are several words in a sentence";
var words = sentence.split(" ");
var index = 0;
var newsentence = "";
function clickit() {
  newsentence += sentence[index];
  index = index + 1;
}
```

Comment: This misses the space between the words.  It also never actually updates the page.

Comment: Of course not, I am just giving him some ideas, not do his work for him.